# Prometheus - Django : connection refused

Tags: django, docker, prometheus

(This is my first time using Prometheus and I'm not very good with Docker/Django yet)

I'm running a Django project in a docker container, and Prometheus with `docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /tmp/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml        prom/prometheus`

In my `docker-compose.yml` I have:

```
...
nginx-proxy:
        build:
            context: ./dockerfiles/nginx-proxy/
            args:
                - DOMAIN_NAME=local.my.url
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - api
            - ...
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/nginx-front/log/:/var/log/nginx

api:
        build:
            context: ./dockerfiles/api/
            args:
                - GUNICORN_WORKERS=20
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./volumes/api/src/:/usr/src/app
...
```

In `/tmp/prometheus.yml` I have:

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
  external_labels:
      monitor: 'my-project-monitor'

rule_files:

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'api'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['api.local.my.url']
```

The `prometheus` job seems to work ok (but those aren't the metrics I'm interested in), the `api` gives the following error from the Promotheus UI:
`Get http://api.local.my.url:80/metrics: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:80: connect: connection refused`

However, when I type in `http://api.local.my.url:80/metrics` in my browser I can see the information correctly. I've tried replacing the URL with my IP address `10.25.2.192` but that doesn't change the result.

I don't understand why it can't connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your prometheus container is on a different network and for it 'localhost' means a different thing. It purposefully does not have access to the host's network (by default).

You can verify that by running `sudo docker network ls` while both of your containers are running.

What you could do is make sure the two containers run on the same network.

In your docker command, that would mean adding `--network [name]` and for docker-compose, it would mean adding a `network:` attribute. That can be done for all the services in the docker-compose file if you add something like this at the bottom of your file:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: [name]
```

Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

To actually create the network outside of docker-compose you can use

```
sudo docker network create -d bridge [name]
```

Comment: Just to note that a quicker way to test this without creating a separate docker network would be to just see the name of the network docker-compose will create (by running `sudo docker network ls`) and just pass that name to the `--network [name]` parameter for your prometheus docker run command.

Comment: I tried changing the docker-compose but I got this error `ERROR: The Compose file './../../../docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.networks: 'default'`

Comment: When setting up a default network, this should be at the root level (e.g. add it to the bottom of your file with no identation). It sounds like you're adding it under services. In the link I've posted, just above 'using a pre-existing-network' you can see 'set up a default network' and see how that block fits within a sample docker-compose file.

Comment: My bad, I had an indentation error. So everything runs once more but I still have the initial error from my post. Should I change the contents of the prometheus.yml file?

Comment: Now that the containers are in the same network, they need to refer to each other by their hostnames. Instead of api.local.my.url maybe try just `api` or `api.nginx-proxy` if you insist on going through nginx. In the latter case you might also need to look at your nginx configuration but if you just use `api:[api-port]` in your prometheus.yml targets, you should be able to talk to the api directly.

Answer (score 0):

***docker inspect name-container***

Go to the end, **Networks** -> **Gateway**
[Image example - docker inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toybl.png)

Add -> `prometheus.yml`
[Image example Prometheus.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Dtec.png)

targets: **IP-GATEWAY:8086**
[Image example Prometheus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDmwC.png)